# Thymeleaf renders to one page errors on another

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I can return a list of cars to `localhost:8080/list` but not in 
`localhost:8080/car`.  My goal is to render the list just below the Car Form in `car.html`.

I have tried two scenarios when rendering a list using Thymeleaf : With controller method `getAllCars()` mapped to `/list` I'm able to render the list on `list.html` however with the same method mapped to `/car` I get en error when trying to render to `car.html`.

I'm sure there is something small that I'm missing here.  Perhaps its my use of controller methods when trying to render the list on `car.html`.  The `html` I successfully used on `list.html` is the same I use when I add it to `car.html` with the Car Form.  I simply comment/uncomment the necessary code to attempt each scenario.

Working Scenario : Using getAllCars() method in CarController mapped to list.html

```
@Controller
public class CarController {

    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;

    //PRESENT VIEW car.html
    @GetMapping("/car")
    public String carForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
        return "car";
    }

    //GET list of cars. render to /list
    @RequestMapping("/list")
    public String getAllCars(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("cars", carService.getAllCars());
        return "list";
    }

    //GET list of cars. Render to /car
//    @RequestMapping("/car")
//    public String getAllCars(Model model) {
//        model.addAttribute("cars", carService.getAllCars());
//        return "car";
//    }

    //POST TO DATABASE
    @PostMapping("/car")
    public void carSubmit(@ModelAttribute Car car) {
        carService.addCar(car);
    }

}
```

list.html   --> this works fine

This is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Car List</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Make</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Year</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- if true, display this       -->
        <tr th:if="${!cars}">
            <td colspan="2"> No Cars Available</td>
        </tr>
        <!--  otherwise, iterate over list and display info      -->
        <tr th:each="car : ${cars}">
            <td><span th:text="${car.id}">Id</span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${car.make}">Make</span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${car.model}">Model</span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${car.year}">Year</span></td>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Non-Working Scenario : Using getAllCars() method in CarController mapped to car.html

For brevity, see commented getAllCars() method in above CarController
car.html  --> this does not work

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Car Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/car}" th:object="${car}" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p>Make: <input type="text" th:field="*{make}" /></p>
    <p>Model: <input type="text" th:field="*{model}" /></p>
    <p>Year: <input type="text" th:field="*{year}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>

<h1>Car List</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <!-- if true, display this       -->
    <tr th:if="${!cars}">
        <td colspan="2"> No Cars Available</td>
    </tr>
    <!--  otherwise, iterate over list and display info      -->
    <tr th:each="car : ${cars}">
        <td><span th:text="${car.id}">Id</span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${car.make}">Make</span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${car.model}">Model</span></td>
        <td><span th:text="${car.year}">Year</span></td>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the error I am facing

```
2019-08-27 12:30:32.519 ERROR 22384 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "car": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "!cars" (template: "car" - line 33, col 9)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "!cars" (template: "car" - line 33, col 9)
```

Comment: In case you still have the issue, which version of thymeleaf are you using?

Comment: Jorge.V - I'm bringing in thymeleaf with `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">` on `car.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got your problem. You are redirecting to `car.html` page with controller

```
 @GetMapping("/car")
    public String carForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
        return "car";
    }
```

In the same page you are both showing your car list and saving with form. But you hadn't put `cars` with a `model` in this controller. That's why you are getting a template error. To resolve this problem you need to put `cars` in the previous controller. So modify your controller

```
 @GetMapping("/car")
    public String carForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
        return "car";
    }
```

to

```
@GetMapping("/car")
public String carForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
    model.addAttribute("cars", carService.getAllCars());
    return "car";
}
```

Now after posting car you have to redirects to a page. But you didn't do that. So modify your controller

```
 @PostMapping("/car")
    public void carSubmit(@ModelAttribute Car car) {
        carService.addCar(car);
    }
```

to

```
 @PostMapping("/car")
    public String carSubmit(@ModelAttribute Car car) {
        carService.addCar(car);
        return "redirect:/car"
    }
```

Hope it will work. Give a shout!

Comment: Thanks - just tried this out in my app.  Both the form and the list show on `car.html` now however when I try to submit new car data in the form I get the following error in my console : `2019-08-28 08:08:08.079 ERROR 22736 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-4] Exception processing template "car": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "!cars" (template: "car" - line 33, col 9)

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "!cars" (template: "car" - line 33, col 9)`

Comment: It is failing from the start because "cars" is not a boolean, so you can't do "!cars" on the th:if. I asked you which version of thymeleaf you are using to build a correct conditional. The version you are using is not given by the html header, but the dependency if you are using gradle/maven or the .jar you are importing into your project as a lib.

Comment: @wallwalker I have edited my answer. Please check and let me know!

Comment: @Avijit Barua - Working now!  Thank you.

Comment: @wallwalker Then please mark this answer as accepted one by clicking right sign. And obviously I would except a upvote also

Comment: @Jorge.V - thanks for your patience : Looking under External Libraries I see thymeleaf version : `3.0.11`  - after adding a `redirect` to my `carSubmit()` handler per @Avijit Barua, the app is working now.  My understanding is that in  `<tr th:if="${!cars}"></tr>`, when the statement resolves to `true`, display `<td colspan="2"> No Cars Available</td>`.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Avijit Barua - Done!

Answer (score 0):

It's saying there's an issue with the expresion `!cars` which can be found in your `car` template:

```html
    <tr th:if="${!cars}">
        <td colspan="2"> No Cars Available</td>
    </tr>
```

However the attribute passed to the car template in `carForm` is `car` and not `cars`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that, you are redirecting to `car.html` with 2 different methods. 
So only the first one, ie

```
@GetMapping("/car")
public String carForm(Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
   return "car";
}
```

is working and not,

```
@RequestMapping("/car")
    public String getAllCars(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("cars", carService.getAllCars());
    return "car";
}
```

so either you can do like,

> ```
> @GetMapping("/car")
> public String carForm(Model model) {
>    model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
>    return getAllCars(model);
> }
> ```

or use any one method exactly, or even give different url mappings for both

> Also please let me know why exactly you have commented out the
>   `getallcars` method? Are you getting any ambiguous mapping error while
>   uncommenting the  method.

Comment: Hi!  Thank you. As I already tried Avijit's suggestion, I did try your suggestion of             `@Autowired
    private CarService carService;

    @GetMapping("/car")
    public String carForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
        return getAllCars(model);
    }`  - the problem I am running into now is that intelliJ says it can not resolve method `getAllCars(model);` -  Hmmm... I commented out the second `getAllCars()` because I wanted to just turn on/off easily which URL I could map to for testing.  I need to show form & list on same page for this app.

Comment: You'll need to keep  both methods un-commented. Also either give a different URL mapping to that second method, or don't provide a mapping at all.